# BeautifulSoup: findAll doesn't find the tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm sorry about the many questions I post, but I have no idea what to do about this bug: when testing this [page](http://www.wired.com/2016/08/cape-watch-99/), with simple `p`s

```
ab=soup.find("article", {"itemprop":"articleBody"})
p=ab.findAll("p")
print(len(p))  #gives 1
```

There are many `p` tags, but I get only the first. 
  I tried to copy-paste the whole `<article itemprop="articleBody">` html text into a string and passed it to a new `BeautifulSoup` object. Searching that object for `p` gave all the desired tags (14).

Why the usual approach doesn't work? Are the `p` tags loaded dynamically here (but the html code looks pretty normal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the parser:

```
In [21]: req = requests.get("http://www.wired.com/2016/08/cape-watch-99/")

In [22]: soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

In [23]: len(soup.select("article[itemprop=articleBody] p"))
Out[23]: 26

In [24]: soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

In [25]: len(soup.select("article[itemprop=articleBody] p"))
Out[25]: 1
In [26]: soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html5lib")

In [27]: len(soup.select("article[itemprop=articleBody] p"))
Out[27]: 26
```

You can see *html5lib* and *lxml* get all the p tags but the standard *html.parser* does not handle the broken html as well. Running the article html through  [validator.w3](https://validator.w3.org/) you get a lot of output, in particular:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But why is it, when I use both `html.parser` and `lxml` on a separate `article_body` html, I get only 14 `p` in each case:
`soup3=BeautifulSoup(article_body, "html.parser")` `le(soup3.findAll("p"))` (len is 14), `soup4=BeautifulSoup(article_body, "lxml")`, `len(soup4.findAll("p"))` (14 too). Isn't it the same as when I use the `lxml` on the main `<html>` tag, search for `article` and then search `article` for `p`? The result should be 26 too.

`article_body` html I got through element inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is giving only one p because when your are parsing soup and trying to see what it has parsed,it is getting only one paragraph 
see below code

```
ab = soup.find("article", {"itemprop": "articleBody"})
print ab
```

the output is

```
<article class="content link-underline relative body-copy" data-js="content" itemprop="articleBody">
<p>Not every update about a superhero movie is worthy of great attention. Take, for example, <a href="http://www.slashfilm.com/aquaman-setting/">the revelation</a> that not all of <em>Aquaman</em> will take place underwater</p></article>
```

since you are finding item under article tag and soup close the search when it find the closing article tag, and therefore its returning 1 as len of p which is correct as per your current code

Comment: The problem is with the html it contains extra "</a>" tag present after underwater , when i gone through the source code it observed it, see this is html source      {<article class='content link-underline relative body-copy' data-js='content' itemprop="articleBody">

   <p>Not every update about a superhero movie is worthy of great attention. Take, for example, <a href="http://www.slashfilm.com/aquaman-setting/">the revelation</a> that not all of <em>Aquaman</em> will take place underwater</a>} , the soup things that its closing of article tag hence its printing it as </article>