# Beautifulsoup "findAll()" does not return the tags

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to build a scraper to get some abstracts of academic papers and their corresponding titles [on this page](https://www.elsevier.com/en-xs/search-results?query=catalyst%20for%20water%20splitting&labels=journals&page=1).

The problem is that my `for link in bsObj.findAll('a',{'class':'search-track'})` does not return the links I need to further build my scraper. In my code, the check is like this:

```
for link in bsObj.findAll('a',{'class':'search-track'}):
     print(link)
```

The for loop above does print out anything, however, the `href` links should be inside the `<a class="search-track" ...</a>`.

I have referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029430/beautifulsoup-findall-doesnt-find-the-tags?rq=1), but changing the Beautifulsoup parser is not solving the problem of my code. I am using `"html.parser"` in my Beautifulsoup constructor: `bsObj = bs(html.content, features="html.parser")`.

And the `print(len(bsObj))` prints out "3" while it prints out "2" for both `"lxml"` and `"html5lib"`.

Also, I started off using `urllib.request.urlopen` to get the page and then tried `requests.get()` instead. Unfortunately the two approaches give me the same `bsObj`.

Here is the code I've written:

```
#from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import ssl


'''
The elsevier search is kind of a tree structure:
"keyword --> a list of journals (a journal contain many articles) --> lists of articles
'''
address = input("Please type in your keyword: ") #My keyword is catalyst for water splitting
#https://www.elsevier.com/en-xs/search-results? 
#query=catalyst%20for%20water%20splitting&labels=journals&page=1
address = address.replace(" ", "%20")
address = "https://www.elsevier.com/en-xs/search-results?query=" + address + "&labels=journals&page=1"

journals = []
articles = []

def getJournals(url):
    global journals

    #html = urlopen(url)
    html = requests.get(url)
    bsObj = bs(html.content, features="html.parser")

    #print(len(bsObj))
    #testFile = open('testFile.txt', 'wb')
    #testFile.write(bsObj.text.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict') +'\n'.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'))
    #testFile.close()

    for link in bsObj.findAll('a',{'class':'search-track'}):
        print(link) 
        ########does not print anything########
        '''
        if 'href' in link.attrs and link.attrs['href'] not in journals:
            newJournal = link.attrs['href']
            journals.append(newJournal)
        '''
    return None


# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

getJournals(address)
print(journals)
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is in my code that the for loop does not print out any links? I need to store the links of journals in a list and then visit each link to scrape the abstracts of papers. By right the abstracts part of a paper is free and the website shouldn't have blocked my ID because of it.

Comment: Can you simply post the exact url used by `html = requests.get(url)`?

Comment: @JackFleeting The link is here:  https://www.elsevier.com/en-xs/search-results?query=catalyst%20for%20water%20splitting&labels=journals&page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is dynamically loaded with jscript, so Beautifulsoup can't handle it directly. You may be able to do it using Selenium, but in this case you can do it by tracking the api calls made by the page ([for more see, as one of many examples, here.](https://kiwidamien.github.io/using-api-calls-via-the-network-panel.html)

In your particular case it can be done this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import json

#this is where the data is hiding:
url = "https://site-search-api.prod.ecommerce.elsevier.com/search?query=catalyst%20for%20water%20splitting&labels=journals&start=0&limit=10&lang=en-xs"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(html.content, features="html.parser")


data = json.loads(str(soup))#response is in json format so we load it into a dictionary
```

Note: in this case, it's also possible to dispense with Beautifulsoup altogether and load the response directly, as in `data = json.loads(html.content)`. From this point:

```
hits = data['hits']['hits']#target urls are hidden deep inside nested dictionaries and lists
for hit in hits:
    print(hit['_source']['url'])
```

Ouput:

```
https://www.journals.elsevier.com/water-research
https://www.journals.elsevier.com/water-research-x
```

etc.

Comment: Oh thank you so much your code fixes it!! But since this API method doesn't use the original URL link and the link shown here only returns results of the first page, how can I keep scraping the 2nd, 3rd, pages of the search-result page? I am sorry I am not very familiar with API operations, but may I ask how the `site-search-api.prod.ecommerce` API works to get info from the site instead of using an API key generated by Elsevier?

Comment: Oh I think I have found a way to solve the problem! I have scraped more URLs by increasing the number in `&limit=0`. Thank you very much for the inspiration!

Comment: @DanielQiao Glad it helped! Yes, there's still a whole lot to be learned about dynamically loaded pages... Good luck. BTW, don't forget to accept the answer if you are done.